# Deploy managed metadata with a Core solution

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, sharepoint-on-prem

I want to build a core solution in SharePoint 2013. 
I need to deploy two lists, in one of them will be defined a field that uses a taxonomy picker.

But now I am wondering how I can provision the Managed Metadata Term and Termsets with a WSP File (Core Solution). 
Is it possible to do it declarative (like a Choice Field)?

A Quick search on google resulted into this site http://blogs.myfirstsharepoint.de/allgemein/managed-metadata-tipps-fr-taxonomie-ohne-tcken

But is this the only method to perform a deployment?

Comment: Is this all that the solution does? If yes, I would recommend that you look at Powershell to provision the lists and termsets.

Comment: No not at all. It deploys workflows to and also site layouts. I minimized the description to get the focus on the question :)